# How to use custom R modules in Azure ML env.?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

So, I have a program with multiple functions. Each of these functions has been packaged in zip files with the XML, and all have been successfully uploaded as custom modules to Azure.

I'm trying to call these functions via a custom R script. Something like:

```
# Map 1-based optional input ports to variables
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame

# Importing my custom module
source("src/A.R")
source("src/B.R")
source("src/C.R")

#function A performs work and calls function B & C while doing so. 
for(i in 1:100){
  a = A(data[i,])
}

data.set <- data.frame(a)
# Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port

maml.mapOutputPort("data.set");
```

However, this is failing. Completely. It doesn't even import any of the custom modules with the

```
source("src/A.R")
```

commands.

How do I do this?

Additionally, the custom modules call each other during the course of their processing. Azure Ml would support that behavior, right?

(the project has at the end moment been ported to this platform, so I'm stuck with trying to ensure my code works on something it wasn't designed for.)